# Boost.Asio: wrapping with different `strand`s several times

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, asio

Suppose that I have two connections each having their respective `strand` for thread safety. Those connections are not operating alone, and they can talk to each other in some way. During this communication phase, handlers must be synchronized such that, no two handlers can modify connection objects at the same time.

So, in order to achieve that, could I use two `strand::wrap`s in a nested way?

For example, consider the following pseudo-code:

```
class connection /* connection actually uses shared_ptr's to ensure lifetime */
{

public:

    connection *other       /* somehow set */;
    strand          strnd   /* somehow initialized correctly */;
    socket          sock    /* somehow initialized correctly */;
    streambuf       buf;

    int a   /* shared variable */;

    void trigger_read() // somewhat triggered
    {
        // since operations on sock are not thread-safe, use a strand to
        // synchronise them
        strnd.post([this] {
            // now consider the following code,
            async_read_until(sock, buf, '\n',
            this->strnd.wrap /* wrapping by this->strnd is for sure */([](...) {
                 // depending on the data, this handler can alter both other
                 // and this
                 other->a ++;   // not safe
                 this->a --;    // this is safe as protected by this->strnd
            }));

            // can protect them both by something like,
            async_read_until(sock, buf, '\n',
                this->strnd.wrap(other->strnd.wrap([](...) {
                    // depending on the data, this handler can alter both other
                    // and this
                    other->a ++;   // not safe
                    this->a --;    // this is safe as protected by this->strnd
            })));
            // this???
        });

    }

};
```

Comment: Is it such a hard or bad question :/

Comment: Wow. You should buy more patience, pronto.

Comment: I like the question and it's not very easy to answer (otherwise the OP should have answered it himself). The downvote isn't mine and I countered it with an upvote.

Comment: @sehe Thank you. If the question is good, then it's great! I feel like it can help me understanding the library further. Waiting for your answer excitedly.

Answer (score 1):

What you proposed would not be free of potential race conditions in Boost.Asio (1.65.1). Consider the snippet from your post below,

> ```
> // can protect them both by something like,
> async_read_until(sock, buf, '\n',
>     this->strnd.wrap(other->strnd.wrap([](...) {
>         // depending on the data, this handler can alter both other
>         // and this
>         other->a ++;   // not safe
>         this->a --;    // this is safe as protected by this->strnd
> })));
> ```

and recall that `strand::wrap` behaves identically to `strand::dispatch` on invocation. If we consider it in this context, then we can deduce the following. But first let's require the wrapped strands using dispatch and lambdas (for illustration purposes).

```
async_read_until(sock, buf, '\n', [...](...){  // lambda1
    this->strnd.dispatch([...]{                // lambda2
        other->strnd.dispatch([...]{           // lambda3
           other->a ++;
           this->a --:
        });
    });
 });
```

When `async_read_until` completes it will invoke the equivalent of `lambda1` which will call dispatch on the connections own strand. Whether invoked immediately or later, this will result in `lambda2` being invoked in a setting safe for the manipulation of `this->a`. In `lambda2` we invoke `other->stnd.dispatch` which and by the guarantees of that strand `lambda3` will either be invoked immediately **or posted to `other->strnd`**. In either case `lambda2` completes as does the guarantees for concurrency provided by `this->strnd`. If `lambda3` was posted to `other->strnd` when it is eventually invoked to access `this->a --` we will no long have the guarantees provided for the invocation of `lambda2`.

---

## Inspecting the headers

We can also see this by inspecting the `do_dispatch` function in the  [`strand_service` (Boost 1.65)](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/boost/asio/detail/impl/strand_service.ipp) with the following counter example, as `wrap` simply invokes `dispatch` on the strand when the function is invoked.

Consider a handler wrapped by 2 strands, `strand1` and `strand2`:

```
func = strand1.wrap(strand2.wrap(some_handler));
```

and without the underlying `io_service` being run. Then when `func` is invoked, as we are not in a current invocation of the strand, [`dispatch`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/boost/asio/detail/impl/strand_service.hpp) will not immediately invoke the function, but instead request `do_dispatch` to perform further processing. In `do_dispatch` since we are not currently running in the I/O service, but no other handler has the strand's lock, `do_dispatch` will not signal immediate invocation, but will instead push the handler onto the ready queue for `strand1`. Once on the ready-queue the handler is simple invoked once the ready-queue is processed (see `do_complete`).

This means that the point at which `strand2`'s wrapper is invoked to dispatch on `strand2`, `strand1` is completely done with providing it's guarantees. If `strand2`'s dispatch call results in immediate invocation then we are fine, if there is a conflict and the handler must be pushed on the waiting queue of strand2 then there is no telling when it will eventually be called.

In summary, wrapping a handler in multiple strands does not guarantee that the handler will be in an environment with the concurrency guarantees of all the strands.